# Le fait de prétexter

Tags: traduction, anglais

Existe-t-il un mot français pour traduire pretexting dans le contexte suivant là où l'infinitif ne suffit pas à en retranscrire tout le sens ?

> Pretexting can also be used to...

[Lien vers l'article](https://www.social-engineer.org/framework/influencing-others/pretexting/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suivant le sens attendu de *pretexting*, voici trois propositions :

> La simulation peut aussi être utilisée pour...
>
> L'[imposture](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imposture) peut aussi être utilisée pour...
>
> L'usurpation (d'identité) peut aussi être utilisée pour...

Comment: J'ai ajouté un lien vers l'article complet pour permettre une meilleure compréhension du problème, car ces réponses bien que pertinentes dans un cas général ne répondent pas à mon problème ici..

Comment: J'ai ajouté *imposture* qui se rapproche du sens attendu.

Comment: Imposture se rapproche un petit peu plus de ce que je recherche, je laisse la question ouverte encore un petit peu dans l'espoir d'autres réponses, dans le cas contraire je validerai la votre.

Comment: Étant donné le contexte j'utiliserais en premier lieux le terme d'usurpation d'identité (au moins dans le titre), "l'imposture" ou encore "la méthode" peuvent être utilisés dans la suite du texte pour éviter la répétition. J'éviterais le terme de simulation qui peut être confondant vu que l'on parle d'informatique.

Comment: @Atarax L'article traite d'une technique plus large que l'usurpation d'identité puisqu'elle inclut aussi la création de toute pièces d'une nouvelle identité ainsi que les fausses déclarations (expérience, diplômes...). *Imposture* me semble le plus adapté à cette variété de cas.

Comment: @Jiliagre, d'accord avec vous. Je n'avais pas réalisé que l'usurpation d'identité était limité aux personnes existantes (et vivantes d'ailleurs vu la définition)... ce qui voudrait dire qu'on ne peut usurper l'identité d'un mort ? désolée je m'éloigne du sujet.

Comment: @Atarax On peut usurper l'identité d'une personne décédée, mais pas l'identité d'une personne n'ayant jamais existé...

Answer (score 4):

Je suis plutôt d'accord avec le choix de termes d'une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29426), surtout avec les phrases de l'article. Ce dernier renvoie à [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretexting) qui donne « the practice of presenting oneself as someone else in order to obtain private information » (voir aussi [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pretext#Verb) ; aussi [*to blag*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blag#Verb) en BrE avec une formulation au lexique davantage axée sur l'objectif que le moyen) : ce sens n'existe pas en français à ma connaissance (voir [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9texter), [Larousse en ligne](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pr%C3%A9texter/63840?q=pr%C3%A9texter#63124), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pr%C3%A9texter)), *prétexter* signifiant « donner un motif, une raison apparente pour justifier un acte, un comportement; alléguer quelque chose » (TLFi). Il ne s'agirait donc pas du *fait de prétexter*, un faux ami à mon avis. Par ailleurs il ne s'agit pas non plus du vol d'identité comme tel ni d'un cas où quelqu'un utilise une information pour faire frauduleusement une transaction etc.

[Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=PRETEXTING&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) a opté pour « soutirer des informations confidentielles » qui ne fonctionne pas avec l'exemple à première vue puisque la locution n'indique pas le moyen employé pour soutirer ces informations. Il suffirait peut-être de la compléter :

> Tenter de soutirer des informations confidentielles par/au moyen d'une
>   l'[imposture](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29426)/en se faisant passer pour X.

C'est davantage ceci que de *prétexter* dont il s'agit à mon avis, mais dans l'article c'est le moyen et non la finalité qui est à l'avant-plan, d'où il me semble la plus grande utilité (et l'économie) des termes présentés ailleurs...

Comment: Merci pour tous ces éclaircissements, je valide imposture et la réponse l'ayant proposé cependant les informations que vous donnez mériteraient d'être ajoutées à sa réponse.

Answer (score 3):

S'agissant du domaine informatique, la lecture du chapitre "Social Engineering" du livre "Sécurité Informatique Ethical Hacking" indique les termes suivants, qui ne sont pas strict équivalents mais qui peuvent convenir vu le contexte :

- La manipulation (plus général, *social dengineering* étant traduit comme manipulation sociale)
- La supercherie

On peut aussi penser à :

- La tromperie
- La duperie